# Amity Cloud Could not resolve all files for configuration - amity-log

Tags: exception, chat

Getting this exception while building, I couldn't find this dependency which is causing this issue in my project

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':common:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':common:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.github.AmityCo.Amity-Social-Cloud-SDK-Android:amity-log:6.10.0.
> Searched in the following locations: